# Html download Java

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have some problem to download correctly html body on Java. I try this:

```
public class HTML {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println(Jsoup.connect("http://www.opsu.gob.ve/portal/principal.html?ir=cpnev_csni&tp=1&ci=24522405").get().html());
    }
}
```

It's works but i have some error downloading the complete html body, the error looks like this:

in console show an element like this:

```
<div id="contenedor_central">
x
</div>
```

But I download the html from Google Chrome and the same id show this:

```
<div id="contenedor_central" style="overflow: auto; padding: 10px; height: 850px; width: 900px;"> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/portal/includes/css/internas.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/portal/includes/css/buscar.css">

<div class="navega">Nosotros &gt; Oficina de Planificación del Sector Universitario&gt;</div><br>
<div class="titulo">Resultados de la Prueba Nacional de Exploración Vocacional</div>
<div class="subtitulo">Resultados de la Búsqueda</div>
<div id="botones"> <div id="atras" class="botonera" onclick="history.back();"></div><div id="print" class="botonera" onclick="window.print();"></div><div id="aumenta" class="botonera" onclick="cambia_fuente(1,'div_contenido','ico_seccion','margen','ico_bold','tabulado');"></div><div id="disminuye" class="botonera" onclick="cambia_fuente(2,'div_contenido','ico_seccion','margen','ico_bold','tabulado');"></div><div id="reestablece" class="botonera" onclick="cambia_fuente(3,'div_contenido','ico_seccion','margen','ico_bold','tabulado');"></div><br><br></div>
 <br><br>
<div id="no_resultado" style="display: none;"></div>

<div id="div_contenido" class="contenido" style="font-size: 9pt;">
<div class="todos_resultados_tabla" id="todos_resultados_tabla" style="display: block;">
    <table width="68%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">  
          <tbody><tr>


.... The next of the content
```

I'm new to this, and I can't find why it's happening?

Why the same url in java don't show the same element content.

I hope you can help me guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there is some JavaScript that manipulates the page after it loads and jsoup only sees the page before JavaScript is executed. If you disable JavaScript in your browser and look at the source it's the same. You could look at something like phantomjs which will allow you to run the JavaScript and then get the html.

Comment: it works perfectly, and now i try to load an search an String in the content, and if it has this String save the file, i do that, but i cant load a sequence of pages, for example "google.com/page1" ,"google.com/page2", "google.com/page3" to +999.999 pages, in the js it works the frist time, but for the next pages it just don't load anything so i use java to create the 999.999 bats files to use with phantomjs, if you know a best way to do that...